# What file is responsible for the login script

Tags: raspbian

My question is simple; what file (I assume it is a single file) is responsible for the login interface you see when you try to log into the pi? I have not been able to locate it and all my searches end up with results about auto scripts as soon as user is logged on.  Specifically, I would like to edit the file.

Comment: Take a look at the .conf files in the /etc/lightdm directory.

Comment: Are you talking about the GUI login, or command line?

Comment: Well actually both but information on either one would be usefull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends which OS distribution you are using.

On Raspbian the default graphical login is [LightDM](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/LightDM/); the "DM" is for [display manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_display_manager_(program_type)).  Note this is distinct from the actual post login [desktop environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment), which by default on Raspbian is [LXDE](http://lxde.org/).

To be excessively literal, then, the file responsible is the LightDM binary, `/usr/bin/lightdm`.  It uses configuration as documented in the link above.

LightDM is started as an [init](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) service.  On Raspbian Wheezy, init is Debian's traditional [SysV style init](https://wiki.debian.org/Init), and the init script responsible is `/etc/init.d/lightdm`.  On Jessie SysV init is replaced with [systemd](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/), and the service file responsible is `/lib/systemd/system/lightdm.service`.

Comment: Thanks for the info. So, since it is binary I guess you could not edit it. For example, making a different background in the GUI login?

Comment: No, although since it is open source you could modify the source and recompile it (but this is a little bit like saying, "Yes, you could remove one kidney" -- learning *how* to do that is another matter).   It also doesn't mean this is the only or best way of doing this...

Comment: ...I would assume there is an easy way by tweaking the configuration, and in fact a quick glance at the docs linked above reveals WRT "changing the wallpaper" that "LightDM does not configure the look of greeters; to do this configure the appropriate greeter" and there are some clues there as to what a "greeter" is; they are evidently not used just by lightdm.   There's also 120 posts returned searching [U&L](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) for "greeter", 20 of which are tagged `lightdm`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found [here](https://arcticdog.wordpress.com/2012/02/08/customising-the-lightdm-gtk-greeter/) that the settings for look are contained in lightdm.conf and greeter.ui. You can completely, change the look of the screen according to your desire without messing with the binary. For example, drawing from the site I mentioned, to change the wallpaper edit the greeter stanza in the config file and add the path to the new background!